# flight prices Italy - Las Vegas

Tags: tickets, price

I'm trying to find a good price for a flight Italy - Las Vegas for May 2023.
I moniterd it since a couple of weeks and I can't find anything below 750 €.
I noticed that prices to other destinations are more or less similar to pre-covid. Since I never flew to Vegas, my question is:

are flights to Vegas always so expensive or it's due to covid/general prices increase? If this is a normal price for such a destination, I will not wait any longer.

Comment: Are you happening to be traveling on or near May 29th (26th - 30th? That's a federal holiday which will push up prices.

Comment: @mkennedy I noticed that, but I will be traveling in the first half of the month (I didn't decide the dates yet)

Comment: Flights to Las Vegas are often more expensive than to other cities in the US because there are few direct flights. Where would you be leaving from? Flights May 10th to 17th from MXP go for less than 650€ with 1 stop max. Do you have constraints on minimum/maximum stay, dzys of the week? Note you could also fly to LA or SFO (nearly 200€ cheaper) and then find a cheap flight to LAS. But spend the night there in both directions to avoid self-connection issues.

Comment: You can fly to LAX and drive to Vegas, would be cheaper than flying direct most likely (and might be faster than taking a connecting flight from LA...)

Comment: yes I also thought about that, but flying to LAX is not convenient since I will have to add 1 night and one more day of car rental. these days car rental is more expensive than a flight, so I would end up paying more than flying to LV. Also an internal flight would not save much, since I will have to pay for 1 night more. I have some flexibility but the total stay will be 12 days. My biggest question was whether these prices are normal or not, since I never checked flights to Vegas. If that's a normal price, I will go for it.

Answer (score 3):

I see flights in early March starting around US$570 from MXP or FCO. Exact price depends (quite a bit) on whether you want to check luggage or not.

In my opinion, this is about as good as it's going to get, but of course, you never know.

Comment: yes unfortunately as soon as you add the checked in luggage, it goes up by 130 $ . so more or less the same price you are talking about. thanks for your feedback